# Bibtex will not load additional references in Overleaf

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I'm using Overleaf and `bibtex`. I have specified a `.bib` file which contains my references, and have placed the following at the end of my document. A small extract below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\begin{document}
    \cite{davidsonmckinnon2002}

    \bibliographystyle{plain}
    \bibliography{bibliography}
\end{document}
```

When adding new references into my `.bib`file, references are shown in the document, but not in the references list at the end.

How to fix this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you tell us your work flow for compiling the document.

Comment: I use Overleaf (http://overleaf.com/), having one document called bibliography.bib, and one main tex-file in the same working directory. The document is continuously compiled each time a new element is added (e.g. a letter or equation) by the browser software at Overleaf.

Comment: This might be a silly question, but does adding the `.bib` extension to the file name reference help (i.e., `\bibliography{bibliography.bib}`)?